# Does SRSetRestorePoint of the system restore API work slower for non-newly-installed OS?

Tags: winapi, system-restore

Is it true that the API to create system restore points (SRSetRestorePoint) works faster on a newly installed Windows OS? It sounds logical because for couple of years the system registry (and whatever other areas are "backed up" by System Restore) grows very much. But my assumption doesn't have a background...

Can anybody provide any evidence about it or disprove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows XP, this is true. XP approaches System Restore in a kind of simpleminded way, it copies files based on their extension. And it covers a [lot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of extensions.

Starting with Windows Vista, System Restore got smarter, it now uses [Shadow Copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636%28WS.10%29.aspx). This is a feature backed in NTFS (won't work on FAT), where files are marked as "also keep this version if someone updates the file". Time to make a shadow copy of the needed files for system restore is now only dependent on the number of files, not the size of files.

But, since the number of files that are covered (and the size of the registry, as you noted) will keep growing as the user installs more stuff, the time needed for a restore point *will* increase. So, the best answer would be "yes it's slower, but not much slower, unless you're on XP".

EDIT: This [article](http://lifehacker.com/#!5466794/the-complete-guide-to-windows-system-restore-its-better-than-you-remember) describes this.

Comment: Thanks for a solid answer, Erik! I'll get acquainted with the links you provided and get back...

Comment: Thanks again for the link. Well, as far as I understand, it states that there's very slight performance improvement if you disable system restore. BUT, it's slight in scope of the OS in general. I actually face with this problem trying to optimize the MSI package installation. It takes almost a minute to create a restore point out of my 2-minutes installation, which is quite significant. Do you think it is a good excuse to suggest users to disable system restore for Windows Installer only?

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko: Not really. System restore's a bit annoying until you actually need it... If your user base are technical, sure, explain it. For end users, I wouldn't recommend anything that could cause even the slightest of problems - they *will* blame you if they can :)

Comment: Right! You've confirmed my guesses. And, he's your bounty! :)